# Click Event for the Image Slider Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just working on the Image Slider with a timer. But there are some issues...

1. Images are out of Sync with its text
2. I need a click event for the thumbnail timer, on click of that the image should change with a clear intervals.

Here is the Link which I am trying:

http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/UgQJG/

Comment: I have a workaround for "Images are out of Sync with its text" If you want to know it I will answer for it only.

Comment: @SaidBakr: Yeah sure answer it

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the sync. problem is solved after a complete loop of showing images, so it is related with the download speed of the images. Suppose you use, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg in your slide show. so you will include them first  in displayed none div before the the div panel you used.

```
    <div style="display:none">
    <img src='1.jpg' />
    <img src='2.jpg' />
    <img src='3.jpg' />
    <img src='4.jpg' />
    </div>

    <div id="panel">
      <div id="title">
      </div>
      <img id="imageSlide" alt="" src="" width="250px"/>
      <div id="desc">
      </div>
    </div>
<script>
//JavaScript slide initiation code here.
</script>
```

This will allow the page to download the images before render the slide show, so images will be ready to be maintained at the same speed with text.

Comment: I open your example and it is working fine! -do you know why? because all the images are saved in the browser's cache- I solved issue like that before using the same technique.

Comment: But the text also should fadein and fadeout as the Image is doing

Comment: @ui1 This is another topic, I don't know how to add fading effect to the text.